# PHP FPDF add new page when Y reach a certain point in foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, fpdf

i have the following codes in FPDF :

```
foreach($dataas $data){

            $this->setFont('Arial','', 7);
            $this->SetY(105);
            $y = $this->GetY();
            $valY += 10;
            $b = $y + $valY;
            $pageH = $this->getPageHeight();
            if($b > 200){
                $this->AddPage();
                $b = 10;
            }
            $this->SetXY(5,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[0],3,$sum++,0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(17,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[1],3,$data['data1'],0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(50,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[2],3,$data['data2'],0,'C');
            $this->SetXY(65,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[3],3,$data['data3'],0,'C');
            $this->SetXY(82,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[4],3,$data['data4'],0,'C');
            $this->SetXY(97,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[5],3,$data['data5'],0,'C');
            $this->SetXY(114,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[6],3,$data['data6'],0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(125,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[7],3,number_format($data['data7'],2,".",","),0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(143,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[8],3,number_format($data['data8'],2,".",","),0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(161,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[9],3,number_format($data['data9'],2,".",","),0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(186,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[10],3,number_format($data['data10'],2,".",","),0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(204,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[11],3,number_format($data['data11'],2,".",","),0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(222,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[12],3,number_format($data['data12'],2,".",","),0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(247,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[13],3,number_format($$data['data13'],2,".",","),0,'L');
            $this->SetXY(272,$b);
            $this->MultiCell($w[14],3,$data['data14'],0,'L');
            $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
    }
```

this is what i get :

page 1

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

page 2

- 6

page 3

- 7

page 4

- 8

but instead i want something like this:

page 1:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

page 2:

- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9
- 10

everytime the value of Y hit 200, it adds a new page and also reset the Y on the new page back to 10 but the Y value outside IF didnt change to 10 and i need the foreach to loop the data.
how do i make Y outside IF set to 10 like the above?
thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you getting only five items per page when each iteration through the loop outputs 15 items before attempting to add another page?

Comment: with my IF($b>200) and the header as well

Comment: I suggest using the script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3).